# Haskell: "Reading" ByteString

Tags: haskell

How do I convert a ByteString representation of an Integer to ... well Integer?
Is there a special read function for ByteStrings or do I have to unpack first than use normal read?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`readInt` or `readInteger`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#g:23) from `Data.ByteString.Char8`. If you want to read some other type of data, you'll need to write your own parser; the best choice is probably [attoparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec), which is a library for writing fast `ByteString` and `Text` parsers, similar to Parsec.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to ehird's excellent suggestions, you can also use [Data.Binary.Get](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/binary/latest/doc/html/Data-Binary-Get.html) for reading fixed-length integers.

```
ghci> :m +Data.Binary.Get
ghci> :t runGet getWord64le
ByteString -> Word64
```